# AmCharts 4: change categoryAxis color by using fill property

Tags: amcharts4

I have an amCharts 4 column chart and I'm trying to set the category name to white because my background color page is dark blue, but when I use categoryAxis.fill = am4core.color("#FFFFFF") it does not change the color to white, it keeps it black, but when I try to change the stroke color using categoryAxis.stroke = am4core.color("#FFFFFF") it changes its stroke color perfectly.

Why when I use .fill it does not work?

Here is my categoryAxis definition. What am I doing wrong?

```
 var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
 categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "category";
 categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
 categoryAxis.fill = am4core.color("#FFFFFF");
 categoryAxis.stroke = am4core.color("#FFFFFF");
 categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;
 categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
 categoryAxis.renderer.cellStartLocation = 0.05
 categoryAxis.renderer.cellEndLocation = 0.95
 categoryAxis.renderer.fontSize = 15;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found out what fix my problem. But I'm not using categoryAxis.fill anymore.

I set up classes to the amCharts elements using

```
am4core.options.autoSetClassName = true;
```

and set up this css on my page

```
 g.amcharts-AxisLabel-group {
        fill: #FFFFFF !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the way simpler

`categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add('fill', (fill, target) => { return (target.fill = am4core.color('#fff')); });`

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer.